# How to Text Wrap - DataGridView Yii2 framework

Tags: php, datagridview, yii2, word-wrap

I have been trying to find an answer in the internet but i can find anything. I am quite new in web developing so it is a problem for me to figure it out.

**Problem**:
Text goes beyound cells when i set max-width for any value. I need to find a way to wrap it. Is it possible to do this by widget properties? Thank you for answer

```
  <?php
     echo GridView::widget([
         'dataProvider' => $provider,
         'options' => ['style' => 'max-height:30px;',
                                    'max-width:10px;',
                      ],
         'columns' => [
             ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
                 'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 30px;']],
             //subject
             [
                 'attribute' => 'subject',
                 'format' => 'text',

                 'label' => 'Subject',
                 'contentOptions'=>[
                     'style'=>
                         ['width: 10px;',],

                 ]
             ],
             //body
             [
                 'attribute' => 'body',
                 'format' => 'text',
                 'label' => 'Body',
                 'contentOptions'=>['style'=> 'max-width: 100px;', 'height: 100px']
             ],
             ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
                 'controller'=>null,
                 'header'=>'Action',
                 'headerOptions' => ['width' => '70'],
             ],
         ],
         'tableOptions' =>['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered'],
     ]);
?>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see the image. please provide it or explain better. Probabily you can't upload image. provide an example in this case

Comment: @scaisEdge well http://screenshot.sh/oAFzkKXyDOrPB

Comment: Why max-height or style  height in your code  ? If you use this setting the text wrap is not useful....

Comment: isnt it similar to this? - http://jsfiddle.net/rzjvnpeu/ i mean your setting width first and then wraping. When i dont set this property (max-width) column lenght is as long as text, so to read everything you need to scroll whole site to right

Comment: No I'm not asked for width but for height. For the width is clear you want define properly this value for a better layout but the width?. Howerver what have you show in jsfiddle is css  you can do with style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `style` declaration is wrong. Yii2 uses [`cssStyleFromArray`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseHtml.php#L1945) to generate the html `style` tag attributes. The correct format is an array of key-value pairs for each property:

```
'contentOptions' => ['style' => ['max-width' => '100px;', 'height' => '100px']]
```

Having said that, it would be better to create a new css rule in your stylesheet and add a class to the column:

```
 'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-wrap']
```

Comment: what should css properties in text wrap class ??

Comment: @981 it should be like `.text-wrap{max-width:"100px";, height:"100px"}`

Answer (score 2):

This worked Perfectly for me:

```
[‘attribute’=>‘whatever’, ‘contentOptions’ => [‘style’ =>‘white-space:pre-line;’],],
```

[found here](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/gridview-column-text-wrap/84313/3)!